# What is the meaning of "TC_GAME_API" between Class and classname

Tags: c++

What is the meaning of TC_GAME_API between Class and classname?

```
#ifdef TRINITY_API_EXPORT_GAME
#  define TC_GAME_API TC_API_EXPORT
#else
#  define TC_GAME_API TC_API_IMPORT
#endif
```

```
template class TC_GAME_API ScriptRegistry<VehicleScript>;
```

I want to know TC_GAME_API meaning.

for below define, I asl can not clearly understand it.

```
#ifdef TRINITY_API_EXPORT_GAME
#define TC_GAME_API TC_API_EXPORT
#else
#define TC_GAME_API TC_API_IMPORT
#endif
```

Comment: `TC_GAME_API` expands to either `TC_API_EXPORT` or `TC_API_IMPORT`. Have you checked what *those* macros expand to?

Comment: As a hint: It's a common way to create a DLL, where functions in the DLL needs to be exported when creating the DLL, and imported when using the DLL.

Comment: And, to follow up on what Some programmer dude said, *classes* can also be exported/imported from DLLs (which seems to be the case here).